Power Query and API
I have built an R API using Plumber. When I debug the API from R all looks good. However when I post the request from Excel Power Query the APi runs calculations once and then I can se it retries again even though Excel has received the response. I have disabled any refreshes etc. I refresh a specific connection using VBA.API returns code 503 and I have a built in check in Power Query
 response = try 
    Web.Contents(apiUrl, [
        Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
        Content = jsonBinary,
        ManualStatusHandling = {503, 500} // Manually handle 503 and 500 status
    ])
otherwise 
    error "API request failed. Please check your connection.",

// Extract metadata and status code from the response
metaData = Value.Metadata(response),
status = metaData[Response.Status]?, // Use ? to handle null metadata gracefully

// Check status and handle the response accordingly
result = 
    if status = 200 then
        Json.Document(response) // Parse JSON if the status is 200
    else if status = 503 then
        error "There is another quote running. Please try again in a few minutes"
    else if status <> null then
        error "Unexpected HTTP Status: " & Text.From(status)
    else
        error "Failed to retrieve response status. Please try again."

Is there a way to make the Power Query do just one request and as soon as 503 is received stop?
